# Android-Getting text from string array

Tags: android, arrays, string

So I wanna display items from a string array in a text view in order by pressing a button for next or previous item.I am pretty newbie at coding so this is what I managed to do.

```
String[] PeopleFactsArray;
Button pplnextbtn, pplprevbtn;
TextView pplfacts;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.people_facts);
    PeopleFactsArray=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.people_facts);
    pplnextbtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pplnextbtn);
    pplprevbtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.pplprevbtn);
    pplfacts=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.pplfacts);
    pplnextbtn.setOnClickListener(new FactSelect());
    pplprevbtn.setOnClickListener(new FactSelect());
    int factcount=0;
    pplfacts.setText(PeopleFactsArray[factcount]);

}
class FactSelect implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView pplfacts = null;
        int factcount=0;
        int factlist=PeopleFactsArray.length;
        pplfacts.setText(PeopleFactsArray[factcount]);
        if (v.getId() == R.id.pplnextbtn)
        {
            for (factcount = 0; factcount < factlist; factcount++)
            {
                factcount = factcount + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.pplprevbtn)
        {
            for (factcount = factlist; factcount > 0; factcount--)
            {

                factcount = factcount - 1;
             }
        }

    }
}
```

and my textview is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/people_layout">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/pplfacts"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Next"
    android:id="@+id/pplnextbtn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="84dp" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Prev"
    android:id="@+id/pplprevbtn"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pplnextbtn"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pplfacts"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/pplfacts" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Share"
    android:id="@+id/pplsharebtn"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/pplnextbtn"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pplfacts"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/pplfacts" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and my string array is as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="people_facts">
        <item>people fact 1</item>
        <item>people fact 2</item>
        <item>people fact 3</item>
        <item>people fact 4</item>
        <item>people fact 5</item>
        <item>people fact 6</item>
        <item>people fact 7</item>
        <item>people fact 8</item>
        <item>people fact 9</item>
        <item>people fact 10</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

when I run it and try to press next or prev buttons my app crashes. if someone could steer me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your onClick implementation with this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int factcount=indexOfCurrentSelection;
        int factlist=PeopleFactsArray.length;
        if (v.getId() == R.id.pplnextbtn)
        {
               if(factcount < factlist-1) factcount = factcount + 1;
        }
        else if (v.getId() == R.id.pplprevbtn)
        {
               if(factcount > 0) factcount = factcount - 1;
        }
        pplfacts.setText(PeopleFactsArray[factcount]);
        indexOfCurrentSelection = factcount;
    }
```

Declare indexOfCurrentSelection as a global variable & initialize it to 0.